# List all Ad Videos from a video id

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I created a custom audience for video views, manually, and notice that automaticly Facebook associated a lot of other videos used on Ads. Any way to search for all ad videos from a seed id video? For instants, I uploaded a video and created Ads Videos with it. How can I list, via API, all this videos using a the uploaded video?

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully got this one working:

/{AD_ACCOUNT}/advideos?fields=source

Comment: This doesn't list all seed videos used to create this AdVideo :-( Just list the AdVideos and it file sources